# Centos 7 no firewall & no systemctl

Tags: centos, firewall, yum, centos7, systemd

I really need help, where can I install systemctl and the firewall for centos 7 min?

I have tried everything including google which has all turned up no results.

Answer (score 3):

`systemctl` is installed with the OS and the firewall is built into the kernel and controlled with `iptables`.